# How can I push an input type: 'radio' to firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I looped through the radio with it 'name' to get the selected 'term' for it value then use a button to add data to database with other values.

```
const inputTerm = document.getElementsByName("terms")

propertyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {

    for (let  i = 0; i < inputTerm.length; i++){
        if(inputTerm[i].checked){
            let pickedTerm = inputTerm[i].value
        }
    }
    
    
    let propertyData = {
        terms: pickedTerm,
        title: inputTitle.value,
        location: inputLocation.value,
      };

  push(addedPropertyInDB, propertyData);
  
  
});
```

With this code `pickedTerm`  is not defined, I want all `propertyData` to get pushed as one to firebase database

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare pickedTerm outside the loop.

```
const inputTerm = document.getElementsByName("terms");
let pickedTerm; // Declare pickedTerm outside the loop

propertyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputTerm.length; i++){
        if (inputTerm[i].checked) {
            pickedTerm = inputTerm[i].value; 
            break;
        }
    }

        let propertyData = {
            terms: pickedTerm,
            title: inputTitle.value,
            location: inputLocation.value,
        };
        push(addedPropertyInDB, propertyData);

});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked , i also placed the whole `for loop` outside the EventListener.
Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the scope of the variable pickedTerm is only valid inside the if statement.

## Scope in JavaScript

Scope is the current context of execution in which values and expressions are "visible" or can be referenced. If a variable or expression is not in the current scope, it will not be available for use.

#### JavaScript has the following kinds of scopes:

- Global scope: The default scope for all code running in script mode.
- Module scope: The scope for code running in module mode.
- Function scope: The scope created with a function.

Read more on [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

For your current script, you would need to declare the `pickedTerm` variable where on the scope where it is being accessed.

And that's it. Happy Coding!!

```js
const inputTerm = document.getElementsByName("terms")

propertyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let pickedTerm = null;
    for (let  i = 0; i < inputTerm.length; i++){
        if(inputTerm[i].checked){
            pickedTerm = inputTerm[i].value
        }
    }
    
    
    let propertyData = {
        terms: pickedTerm,
        title: inputTitle.value,
        location: inputLocation.value,
      };

  push(addedPropertyInDB, propertyData);
  
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps Now i know about Scope in JavaScript

Comment: Happy to share mate!

Answer (score 0):

After few trials and errors.

I created a separate function for looping and it worked as I wanted.

```
    const inputTerm = document.getElementsByName("terms");
    
    function getSelectedValue(inputs) {
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
            return inputs[i].value;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    
    propertyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
        const pickedTerm = getSelectedValue(inputTerm);
    
      
    
    
      let propertyData = {
        terms: pickedTerm,
        title: inputTitle.value,
        location: inputLocation.value,
      };
    
      push(addedPropertyInDB, propertyData);
      console.log(propertyData);
    
    });
```